# Javascript regex everything after a period

Tags: javascript, regex

Need a javascipt regex that matches everything that comes after a period. Tried:

```
var myString="100.00";
var myRegexp = /\..*/;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
if (match[1]!=null) {tail=match[1];}
console.log(tail);
```

Comment: And what happened? Did you try `console.log(match);` to see if it was what you expected?

Comment: Running you code I see that the result is in `match[0]`

Comment: Your code works for me as is, if you add a capture group: `/\.(.*)/`. *also, `console.log(tail)` should go inside the if block*

Answer (score 2):

You're missing what's called a "capture group". The entire regex result is stored in `match[0]`, and subsequent capture groups are placed in `match[1..n]`.

If you turn your regex into `/\.(.*)/`, then `match[1]` should give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should choose what you want to match:

```
var myRegexp = /\.(.*)/;
```